# iPhone - Scroll Down Lines in Chat Room

Tags: ios, scroll, chat

I have an app that incorporates a chat room. Every time someone types something in it, I want it to scroll down to the last line typed. Basically, I want the last thing typed to be the lowest thing on the screen. When I type like ten lines of chat-text, it just goes straight down beneath my view. Here is my code:

```
- (void)scrollToBottom
 {
    CGRect lastLine;
    lastLine.origin.x = 0;
    lastLine.origin.y = self.contentSize.height-1;
    lastLine.size.height = 1;
    lastLine.size.width = 1;

    [self scrollRectToVisible:lastLine animated:NO];
}
```

I call this after posting something using this code:

```
- (void)displayChatMessage:(NSString*)message fromUser:(NSString*)userName {
      [chat appendTextAfterLinebreak:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@: %@", userName, message]];
      [chat scrollToBottom];
}
```

Where I call the appendTextAfterLinebreak to and the code for that is:

```
- (void)appendTextAfterLinebreak:(NSString *)text
{
    self.text = [[self.text stringByAppendingString:@"\n"] stringByAppendingString:text];
}
```

Comment: Are you using a UITextView?

Comment: @LyndseyScott I edited the post to include further code if this helps

Comment: More helpful, but still not quite enough… What sort of structure is "chat"? And you have to be using either a scrollview or textview if you're able to both scroll and append text...

Comment: @LyndseyScott it is a textview

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using a `UITextView`, you can easily scroll to the last line using `scrollRangeToVisible:` instead. Ex:

```
- (void)scrollToBottom {

    NSRange bottom = NSMakeRange(chat.text.length - 1, 1);
    [chat scrollRangeToVisible:bottom];

}
```

Comment: I id this but it wierdly scrolls to the top every time I enter something and then scrolls back to the bottom in a second or two

Comment: Does it scroll up before or after scrollToVisible is called?

Comment: Perhaps it's scrolling up before scrollRangeToVisible, but after appendTextAfterLinebreak… Try my edit.

Comment: I tried the edit but it did not do much. Also, I edited the scroll to bottom thing. I deleted the part with the scrollRangeToVisible and then it stopped scrolling up (but it didnt scroll down either obviously). But, that means that something in that specific function of scrollToBottom is the problem

Comment: Gotcha. Good problem solving! I'm going to need to think a little bit more about why that's happening for you...

Comment: OK, I think it has something to do with the way you have things set up… What happens if you change all instances in self.text in "appendTextAfterLine" to chat.text?

Comment: Unfortunately, this still did not work. I am not sure why though

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49158/discussion-between-lyndsey-scott-and-user2779450)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using a `UIScrollView`, you can use below code.

```
- (void)scrollToBottomAnimated:(BOOL)animated {
    CGFloat y = myScrollView.contentSize.height - myScrollView.frame.size.height;
    [myScrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, y) animated:animated];
}
```

Comment: I updated my post. Look at the new code I uploaded. I dont think i am using a UIScrollView